# How do I achieve adding "count" on the map in Folium?

Tags: python, plotly, folium

I'm working on plotting orders count over US interactive map using Folium. I'm able to plot all the instances but i can't get the map to show the "orders" weight on map, but only as pop up, which isn't help

```py
import pandas as pd
import folium
from folium import Choropleth, Circle, Marker
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import HeatMap, MarkerCluster

# Load the data
orderlist=pd.read_csv("/content/orderlist.csv")

# Drop rows with missing locations
orderlist.dropna(subset=['Lat', 'Long'], inplace=True)
print(orderlist)
```

|  | state_id | orders | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AL | 50 | 32.8067 | -86.7911 |
| 1 | AK | 13 | 61.3707 | -152.404 |
| 4 | AR | 44 | 34.9697 | -92.3731 |
| 5 | AZ | 70 | 33.7298 | -111.431 |
| 6 | CA | 388 | 36.1162 | -119.682 |
| 7 | CO | 70 | 39.0598 | -105.311 |
| 8 | CT | 41 | 41.5978 | -72.7554 |
| 9 | DC | 5 | 38.8974 | -77.0268 |
| 10 | DE | 19 | 39.3185 | -75.5071 |
| 11 | FL | 240 | 27.7663 | -81.6868 |
| 12 | GA | 145 | 33.0406 | -83.6431 |
| 14 | HI | 19 | 21.0943 | -157.498 |
| 15 | IA | 60 | 42.0115 | -93.2105 |
| 16 | ID | 25 | 44.2405 | -114.479 |
| 17 | IL | 157 | 40.3495 | -88.9861 |
| 18 | IN | 96 | 39.8494 | -86.2583 |
| 19 | KS | 35 | 38.5266 | -96.7265 |
| 20 | KY | 74 | 37.6681 | -84.6701 |
| 21 | LA | 66 | 31.1695 | -91.8678 |
| 22 | MA | 93 | 42.2302 | -71.5301 |
| 23 | MD | 118 | 39.0639 | -76.8021 |
| 24 | ME | 13 | 44.6939 | -69.3819 |
| 25 | MI | 150 | 43.3266 | -84.5361 |
| 26 | MN | 67 | 45.6945 | -93.9002 |
| 27 | MO | 108 | 38.4561 | -92.2884 |
| 28 | MS | 36 | 32.7416 | -89.6787 |
| 29 | MT | 20 | 46.9219 | -110.454 |
| 30 | NC | 150 | 35.6301 | -79.8064 |
| 31 | ND | 15 | 47.5289 | -99.784 |
| 32 | NE | 29 | 41.1254 | -98.2681 |
| 33 | NH | 27 | 43.4525 | -71.5639 |
| 34 | NJ | 161 | 40.2989 | -74.521 |
| 35 | NM | 6 | 34.8405 | -106.248 |
| 36 | NV | 29 | 38.3135 | -117.055 |
| 37 | NY | 288 | 42.1657 | -74.9481 |
| 38 | OH | 170 | 40.3888 | -82.7649 |
| 39 | OK | 51 | 35.5653 | -96.9289 |
| 40 | OR | 57 | 44.572 | -122.071 |
| 41 | PA | 200 | 40.5908 | -77.2098 |
| 43 | RI | 5 | 41.6809 | -71.5118 |
| 44 | SC | 70 | 33.8569 | -80.945 |
| 45 | SD | 13 | 44.2998 | -99.4388 |
| 46 | TN | 100 | 35.7478 | -86.6923 |
| 47 | TX | 325 | 31.0545 | -97.5635 |
| 48 | UT | 41 | 40.15 | -111.862 |
| 49 | VA | 121 | 37.7693 | -78.17 |
| 50 | VT | 15 | 44.0459 | -72.7107 |
| 51 | WA | 97 | 47.4009 | -121.49 |
| 52 | WI | 74 | 44.2685 | -89.6165 |
| 53 | WV | 28 | 38.4912 | -80.9545 |
| 54 | WY | 11 | 42.756 | -107.302 |

```
#Map Style 2
map2 = folium.Map([48, -102], zoom_start=4,width="%100",height="%100")
locations = list(zip(orderlist.Lat, orderlist.Long))
cluster = plugins.MarkerCluster(locations=locations,                   
               popups=orderlist["orders"].tolist())  
map2.add_child(cluster)
map2
```

**Here comes the question:
How to show the order number on Map, instead of a pop up?
(Using MarkerCluster) **

Output sample:
Couldn't post the required output sample (You need at least 10 reputation to post images.), Please see it on colab instead

**HEY!! You don't need to copy/paste to work on this code, You can simply play/edit it on colab
then post the answer**
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Fs2Xwoc3DHAZe283X3keVMbIQpRAe3eH?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display text strings as annotations on the map in folium, you can do so by using icons to embed text information in the html.

```
import folium
from folium.features import DivIcon

map2 = folium.Map([45, -102], zoom_start=4, width="%100", height="%100")

for lat,lon,order,state in zip(df.Lat, df.Long, df.orders, df.state_id):
    folium.Marker(location=[lat,lon],
                  icon=DivIcon(
                      icon_size=(32,32),
                      icon_anchor=(0,0),
                      html=f'<div style="font-size:14pt;color:green">{order}</div>'
                  )
                 ).add_to(map2)
map2
```

[image]

Comment: Can we use "MarkerCluster" instead, like this image
[link](https://miro.medium.com/proxy/1*NmXTp8oWUgVuzQs1yeIO9w.png) ?

Comment: The function of the marker cluster is simply to group markers together and display the number of markers in that group, and by clicking on the number, the map zooms in and the details are displayed on the map.

Comment: Or are you looking for text decoration like cluster markers?